# French movie, man living at gas station, can't/won't leave

Tags: identify-this-movie

I just got a request from a friend of mine who is looking for a certain movie, but alas I couldn't help her... maybe you can.

She describes the movie as follows :

It's a french movie about a man who is living at a highway gas station. He cannot leave the gas station due to some psychological trauma ... but he wants to leave because of his girlfriend.
According to my friend there is also some singing like in Bollywood movies.

She saw the movie on german television approximately two years ago on german/french channel ARTE.

I'm sorry I don't know anything else, though I think the "man living at gas station" could be pretty obvious for anybody who has seen the movie ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a French movie, but that the only one I found: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0878674/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_6 trailer: http://www.allocine.fr/video/player_gen_cmedia=18776075&cfilm=128518.html

Comment: @Larme, thanks for looking into it, but it's not that one. I finally found it and posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it myself, the movie in question is ["Das Glück an der Autobahn" ("Comme un air d'autoroute")](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3222994/?ref_=nm_flmg_com_3) :)

The psychological trauma is, that he was raised as a foundling at that gas station... so this is his home and he is quite attached to it... The so called girlfriend is the daughter of the evil gas station magnate who wants to get the gas station, but the boy won't leave. The magnate wants his daughter to marry the man, so that he will leave the station.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) this answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.